# Code formatting with prettier is not working in nest js

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs, eslint, prettier

I am using Visual Studio Code. In my Nest JS project, the code is not formatting according to prettier rules. I already set `.prettierrc` and `.eslintrc`.
Also i have set `formatOnSave: true` from the `settings.json` file.

Portion of my **settings.json** file

```
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

My **.eslintrc** file -

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off'
  },
};
```

And finally my **.prettierrc** file -

```
{
  "useTabs": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "importOrder": ["^[./]"],
  "importOrderSortSpecifiers": true,
  "importOrderSeparation": true
}
```

Can you please tell me what to do to format the code properly?

Comment: How is it not formatting? Can you show an unformatted section after saving?

Comment: Like tab issue. In the line if i puts more tabs, then after save, prettier can not resolve it.

Comment: importOrder is another issue. The imports are not following my prettierrc configuration.

Comment: If you run prettier directly, does the issue get fixed?

Comment: No. But if i use it in functional module, then everything is going fine. The problem is in the class based module.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Typescript is typescript regardless if it's class based or functional based. So when you run `prettier --write path/to/file` you get no modifications? That would seem like a parsing error on prettier's side and possibly should be brought up with them as a bug

Comment: I didn't get any modification when i save the file. May be it’s a bug

Comment: VSCode has tooling to debug the extensions. What's logged in the Prettier extension output? There _must_ be an error that should point you at the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by fixing my `setting.json` file.

I just make `editor.formateOnSave: true` for individual language. Like this way

```
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
```

This works for me.

Another solution was running prettier command.
`prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"`

But for using this command according to my .prettierrc and .eslintrc file you have to ensure some packages as the dev dependency.

- prettier
- eslint
- @trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports
- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
- @typescript-eslint/parser
- eslint-config-prettier
- eslint-plugin-import
- eslint-plugin-prettier
- eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort

Most of the packages come from the nest js boilerplate. If you have not found any package from the boilerplate then install by yourself.

Hopefully, this will be a great solution for those, who are facing this kind of problem like me. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure why NestJS has the default setup the way they do (with an eslintrc.js file along with a prettierrc file, with any config you put in the prettierrc not having any impact/effect). I've found a work-around.

#### Prove problem (optional)

Before the steps to fix, ***'prove'*** that the default NestJS provided `prettierrc`  config-file is having no effect on your code by changing the default `"trailingComma": "none"` (the default is "all"). Now go to any of your src files and add a dangler to the last element in an object .. or create a example object and leave a trailing comma. Then format or format+save.. whatever.. Notice (at least for those of us experiencing this problem) that nothing changes and no warnings are issued from prettier.

#### Fix

- First: Rename your `prettierrc` to `prettierrc.js`.
- Next: Inside your `prettierrc.js` modify the default json obj to an exported object, keeping our test-trailing-comma as "none" : `module.exports = {"singleQuote": true, "trailingComma": "none"}`
- Next, inside the `eslintrc.js` leaving all of the other defaults alone, add an import(require) at the top `const prettierConfig = require('./.prettierrc.js')  module.exports = { ... }`
- Then still in `eslintrc.js` in your rules section, add the following rule : `rules: { 'prettier/prettier': [ 'error', prettierConfig ], ...}`
  I'll attach a link to a screenshot if needed.. but you basically are importing and specifying inside `eslintrc.js` that you want to use the (now importable/requireable) prettierrc.js for formatting prettier rules (which you write out like you'd expect in the prettierrc.js file). You can now check your trailing commas for the lovely red-squigleys ;)
  [eslintrc.js with prettierrc.js in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px01x.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure prettier is enabled in VS Code
2. [Check the "prettier" logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGoai.png) (open a terminal, select the "output" tab. next you need to find Prettier in the list)

In my case the .prettierrc file was not in the root of the project and VS Code couldn't find it. (I just have to change the path to this file or move it to the root of the project)

Answer (score 0):

One reason prettier will skip formatting a file is when the file has syntax error(s) in it.  If prettier can't parse it, it errs on the side of caution and doesn't touch it.

Comment: I think there is no error. Can you check my .prettierrc file? I provided the file above

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was if your Typescript file has errors in it, then Prettier won't reformat it.  As a test, you could try removing sections of the file to see if some portion has an error. Otherwise, can you post the code on github?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was my file's language was actually "[typescriptreact]", had to include that as one of the languages it's defaultFormatter for